# Why can't directly mock object in unittest?

Tags: python, mocking

I'm new to python mocking.
I know we can use mock.patch to mock f1 for f2 testing. Like this:

```
def f1(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    return f1(x) + 5

class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('__main__.f1')
    def test_f2(self, mock_f1):
        mock_f1.return_value = 0
        self.assertEqual(f2(5), 5)
```

But I found if I directly mock f1 in test case like below, it doesn't work. I have no idea why can't just directly mock "f1" at here?

```
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_f2(self):
        f1 = mock.Mock()
        f1.return_value = 0
        self.assertEqual(f2(5), 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) and [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) are in the same package they have a different duties:

1. By `mock.Mock()` you are creating a mock object `f1` (local variable)
2. By `patch('__main__.f1')` you are patching `f1` reference in `__main__` module (the one you are running)

`patch` default behavior is to use mocks to replace the original reference, but you can use it also for installing stubs or fakes: the main duty is **to control the context where you replace the reference**.

Just a tip: take a look to [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5) ... it can enlightening you.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you think that would work. All you're doing is defining a new local variable called `f1` which happens to be an instance of Mock; just as if you'd defined `f1 = "foo"` it doesn't affect the module-level name at all.

Comment: Hi, Daniel. I used mock for f1 in interpreter, it indeed affect f2. So I though it also work for unittest... Does it mean they are in different namespace?

Comment: No, they're in different scopes. This has nothing to do with either Mock or unittest. If you define something inside a function, it doesn't affect anything by that name outside the function (unless you used global, which you shouldn't).

Comment: Thanks. I indeed use "global"